# Simplify serializer class in Django

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I wanted to write serializers for a class of views in Django rest framework that share the same properties. In order to avoid writing duplicated items in all serializers, I came up with the following structure:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from modelserializers import LogModelSerializer


class GenericValueSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    message = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, allow_null=False)


class GenericResponseSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    statusCode = serializers.IntegerField(required=True, allow_null=False)
    statusMessage = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, allow_null=False)


class LoginAppResp(GenericResponseSerializer):
    class LoginAppValue(GenericValueSerializer):
        username = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, allow_null=False)
        token = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, allow_null=False)

    value = LoginAppValue()


class LogsDeviceResp(GenericResponseSerializer):
    class LogsDeviceValue(GenericValueSerializer):
        logs = LogModelSerializer()

    value = LogsDeviceValue(many=True)
```

But I am thinking there must be a more efficient way to achieve what I am doing here. Thanks for your help.

Edit:

the desired structure is as follows:

```
{
    "statusCode":10,
    "statusMessage":"",
    "value":
    {
        "message":"",
        "api specific field 1":{},
        "api specific field N":{}
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you re-implement statusCode and statusMessage? serializers are typically used for response content, not for response status code.

Comment: it's not the same as http response status code.

Answer (score 1):

you can override [to_representation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#to_representationself-instance) to define how each entity is represented. Here is a cleaner example:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from modelserializers import LogModelSerializer


class GenericResponseSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    message = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, allow_null=False)
    statusCode = serializers.IntegerField(required=True, allow_null=False)
    statusMessage = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, allow_null=False)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        inner_value_response = super().to_representation(instance)
        status_code = inner_value_response.pop("statusCode")
        status_message = inner_value_response.pop("status_message")
        return {
            "status_message": status_message,
            "status_code": status_code,
            "value": inner_value_response
        }


class LoginAppResp(GenericResponseSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, allow_null=False)
    token = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, allow_null=False)


class LogsDeviceResp(GenericResponseSerializer):
    logs = LogModelSerializer(many=True)
```